# Image renditions - cropped images not updating

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

We have a public facing internet site using SharePoint 2013. We are using image renditions to display different sized images for the page and content rollups and find this a great feature.

The problem is that after changing the cropped area of the image, the rendition does not update with the newly selected area. Even after waiting for a week the old cropped image is still display.

Looking at the blob cache files, SharePoint is still caching the old version of the cropped image and never seems to update automatically.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hello, we're having exact same problem. Flushing the cache may work for a while but then (sometime in like 10minutes) it fails to update new renditions. Did you find any solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried flushing the blob cache?

[Flush the blob cache](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg277249(v=office.15).aspx)

But be careful when flushing the cache.

> Before you enable the BLOB cache, carefully consider the scenario in which you plan to use it. If your site will be used for heavy collaboration, enabling the BLOB cache might temporarily affect the performance of your site while the files to be cached are first written to the disk. After the files have been stored in the cache, site performance will improve, so take this into consideration when you decide whether or not to enable the cache.

[Blob Caching - be careful when flushing the cache!](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/10/08/blob-caching-be-careful-when-flushing-the-cache.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I did try that exact command as suggested and it doesn't seem to work. I ran the powershell commands on the server under an admin account and no errors return, but all the files still remained in the cache directory. I worked out that if I delete the file associated with the rendition manually it regenerates the image with the correct cropping.

Comment: @Plexus81 Hello, we're having exact same problem. Flushing the cache may work for a while but then (sometimes in like 10minutes) it fails to update new renditions. Do you have any idea what might be the problem? We don't want to flush the cache all time.

Comment: Somehow it is now working for us and I don't know what we did to fix it. Have applied SharePoint CU's and can only think that's what fixed it.